# How to build only upon saving in FDT?

Tags: flash, eclipse, actionscript, fdt

Is it possible to set up FDT so that it only builds the workspace when I save (as opposed to constantly or manually) like it does in Flash Builder (previously Flex Builder) and if so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible in FDT. 
Our incremental builder must run at any time. Otherwise you wouldn't get any autocompletion, error highlighting or anything else. In FDT everything is built on that live parsing feature (that is done when building the workspace).

Answer (score 0):

A guess: [Menu] >> Project >> Build Automatically >> uncheck